# Woocommerce - Add filter to display (or hide) custom checkout field if product ID == #

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields

I created a "my_custom_field" textarea, as the default billing_first_name, billing_address, etc..now I'd like to hide this field if product id # is in cart.
So, I need to check if productID == #, and so remove my_custom_field from the checkout.

Otherwise (maybe better?), I could check if productID == #, and create a custom field for that specific ID (or maybe categories).
What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, to adapt with your custom field and product IDs

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields ( $fields ){

    if ( count( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) == 0 ) {
        return $fields;
    }

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $key => $item ) {
        if( in_array( $items[ 'product_id' ], array('1','2','3') ) ){
            unset( $fields[ 'my_custom_field' ] );
            break;
        }
    }

    return $fields;
}
```